# Update inner join query efficiencies

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, both with ~30,000 rows.  Anywhere where `b.comments` is not null, I want to overwrite `a.comments` with `b.comments`' data.  Seems simple enough - but my query has been running for 45 minutes and I don't think it's working.  There about 3,000 values in `b` that are not null - so a max of 3,000 updates.

I know that syntactically this is *fine*, but I'm wondering if there is a different way I should be writing this query as I cannot seem to get it to run unless I also add in something like `...and batch_id = 12345` to get the number of records down to 1.

```
UPDATE temp3 a
INNER JOIN temp2 b
ON a.batch_id = b.batch_id 
and a.batch_li = b.batch_li
SET 
a.comments = b.comments
WHERE
b.comments is not null;
```

Comment: Could you include details of the indexes (or lack thereof) in your question? Might help the accuracy of any answers.

Comment: There are currently no indexes on the two tables. Just a primary key on `id`, but the `id` fields of the two tables do not relate - which is why I am joining them up by `batch_id` and `batch_li`, which creates a match.

Comment: Try putting a nonclustered index on both - use `batch_id` and `batch_li` as the keys, and make sure to include `comments`. The order in which you include them depends on the contents of the columns - I'd read up on that before you make a decision.

Comment: that could definitely help, and I hadn't thought of that.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Let us know how it goes. To be honest, unless you have a really busy/underpowered DB, I don't know how the query could take 45+ mins even without an index, but hopefully indexes will help.

Comment: Odd.  Added the index to both tables - query finished in 4.53 seconds.  Looks like that did the trick! :)

Comment: Awesome, submitted an answer.

Comment: Read from the following link to optimize your update query.
[enter link description here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/119621/how-to-update-10-million-rows-in-mysql-single-table-as-fast-as-possible)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Taken from comment)

Try putting a nonclustered index on both - use batch_id and batch_li as the keys, and make sure to include comments. The order in which you include them depends on the contents of the columns - I'd read up on that before you make a decision.

Comment: More specifically, a 'composite' `INDEX(batch_id, batch_li)` (in either order).

Comment: And "index on both" could be misinterpreted as `INDEX(batch_id), INDEX(batch_li)`, which is not as good.

Comment: It is risky to link to Q&A that is not specifically related to MySQL/MariaDB.  That link talks about SQL Server and mentions some things that do not apply to MySQL.  In a composite index the relative selectivity (or cardinality) does not matter for the query in hand.

Comment: And, to quote one of the answers "For queries that are performing an equality search on all columns in the index there is no significant difference."  But, again, it is risky to point to that because the index type was "Hash", which InnoDB does not use.

Answer (score 1):

The following link is going to explain to you about the cross table update:

[How to update 10 million+ rows in MySQL single table as Fast as possible?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/119621/22336)